# Is there a way to perform a digital signature with a JSON format? Like XadES, but simpler

Tags: json, certificate, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

I'm signing documents and adding a timestamp seal using the XadES-T format. I think that a JSON format would simplify the signature and validation process, is there a way to sign documents and add a timestamp seal in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

JWT signatures itself does not include timestamps in its spec. But you could wrap the JSON in a PKCS#7 Content Signed Message with a timestamp.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with python?